# Dynamic allocate array of struct for Open GL in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, opengl, primitive-types

I'm beginner in Open GL but I already can draw simple triangle, rectangle etc.

My problem is:

I have the structure and static array of that structure

```
typedef struct {
    GLKVector3 Position;
} Vertex;

const Vertex Vertices[] = {
    {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}},
    {{0.5, 0.0, 0.0}},
    {{0.5, 0.5, 0.0}},
    {{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}},
    {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}}
};

...some code
```

but I need array of vertices create dynamically... :(

Example:

```
typedef struct {
    GLKVector3 Position;
} Vertex;

  instance variable - iVertices of type Vertex

- (void) viewDidLoad {
   int numOfVertices = 0;
   Vertex vertices[] = {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
   [self addVertex:vertices atIndex:numOfVertices];
   numOfVertices ++;
   Vertex vertices[] = {{0.5, 0.0, 0.0}};
   [self addVertex:vertices atIndex:numOfVertices];
   numOfVertices ++;
   Vertex vertices[] = {{0.5, 0.5, 0.0}};
   [self addVertex:vertices atIndex:numOfVertices];
}

- (void) addVertex:(Vertex) vertex atIndex:(int) num {
   iVertices[num] = vertex;
}

...and somewhere
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             sizeof(iVertices),
             iVertices,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

and this is not allowed in Objective-C or I don't know how to do it :(

malloc nor callow doesn't help to me...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem here is that you can't just take the sizeof an array that is an instance variable because it's a pointer which will return a size of 8. Instead you're going to have to save the count of the array somewhere else as another instance variable (or use numOfVertices) and multiply it by the `sizeof(int)`. So something like `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numOfVariable*sizeof(int), iVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);` should work for your case.

Comment: yep - thanks! 
And what must I do to "reallocation" that variable? realloc(void*, size_t) or malloc again? And must I manage memory by free() (i use ARC)?
Thanks

Comment: I've discovered, I have to code - free(void *) to correct memory management and I've discovered, I have to use realloc(void *, size_t) instead of malloc(size_t).
I'm sorry for additional question....